# Post Request returns an error observable in Angular despite having been successfully executed at the back-end yet postman returns the correct response

Tags: angular, rxjs

All my angular post requests are returning an error observable despite having excuted successfully at the server side. I don't know what am doing wrongly.

COMPONENT:

```
 this.postInit.postInitialSetup(this.userForm).subscribe(

    (data: string) => {

      if (data === 'Posted Successfully') {
        this.userForm.reset();
        this.router.navigate([this.path]);
      }
    },

    (error: any) => {
      this.errored = true;
      this.serviceErrors = error;

    }

  );
```

SERVICE MAKING THE HTTP REQUEST:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from 
 '@angular/common/http';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
 import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
  import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

 @Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
 export class SetupService {

initialSetUpUrl = 'api/initialSetup';
httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
})
 };
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }



postInitialSetup(postData: FormGroup) {

return this.http.post(this.initialSetUpUrl, postData.value, 
this.httpOptions).pipe(

  map((data: string) => {
    return data;
  }),


  catchError(this.handleError)

);

  }



 private handleError(errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) {

if (errorResponse.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
  // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
  console.error('An error occurred:', errorResponse.error.message);
} else {
  // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
  // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
  console.error(
    `Backend returned code ${errorResponse.status}, ` +
    `body was: ${errorResponse.error}`);
  }
  // return an observable with a user-facing error message
  return throwError('Something bad happened; please try again later.');
}
```

}

This is the data that am sending to the server[image: Befor posting]

This is the response after posting:[image]

Can some one please help me to identify what i could be doing wrongly in my service code or component code considering that am relatively new to angular and the observables at large.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that your are expecting your data in the `.subscribe()` to be a string:

```
 (data: string) => {
    ...
 },
```

There you should have a `HttpResponse` object.

Then you can check:

```
 (data: HttpResponse) => {
    if (data.status === 200) { // do something }
 }
```

Comment: There is this Generic type 'HttpResponse<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).ts(2314) that i don't know what to do with it

Comment: @Googo did you try *providing the type argument*, as [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/http) show?

Comment: this.postInit.postInitialSetup(this.userForm).subscribe(


        (data: HttpResponse<any>) => {
          if (data.status === 200) {
            this.userForm.reset();
            this.router.navigate([this.path]);

          }
        },



        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          this.errored = true;
          this.serviceErrors = error;

        }

      );
This is how i have implemented it but it still behaves  incorreclty

Comment: @Googo you can also use 'HttpBaseResponse' when you don't know what kind of argument you have to use as argument.

Comment: this.postInit.postInitialSetup(this.userForm).subscribe(


        (data: HttpResponseBase) => {
          if (data.status === 200) {
            this.userForm.reset();
            this.router.navigate([this.path]);

          }
        },



        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          this.errored = true;
          this.serviceErrors = error;

        }

      ); Am still getting the same error

Comment: @Googo Check the error message in the browser console and open the details, (click the little arrow). You see there often the reason of the failure

Comment: setup.service.ts:47 Backend returned code 200, body was: [object Object]
handleError @ setup.service.ts:47
error @ catchError.js:29
_error @ Subscriber.js:75
error @ Subscriber.js:55
_error @ Subscriber.js:75
error @ Subscriber.js:55
notifyError @ OuterSubscriber.js:7
_error @ InnerSubscriber.js:14
error @ Subscriber.js:55
onLoad @ http.js:2466
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:391
onInvokeTask @ core.js:39679
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:390
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:168
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:465
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:1603

Comment: Benjamin, my point is that it should not be caught as an error since it was successfully posted and returns status code of 200

Comment: @Googo Oh, I see, you should try `any` instead of `string` in the `.pipe( map() => {})` of your SetupService.
There you should have an Object representing your response data.

Comment: @Benjamin  I have actually realized that the problem is on the data sent from the server. Am using express and i think i need to find a way to format it before sending it to the client